# Running a Python interpreter from Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I have a webapp that is built in Rails, but I'm working with graphs and Python has far better graph libraries (namely, Graph-Tool). There are on the order of 10k lines of code written already, so it would be a hassle to switch to Django. However, the work I'm doing involves querying very, very large graphs, ones that would take a lot of time to load into the interpreter. Is there a way to have a Python interpreter somewhere that Rails controls, with actions like "Load the graph" and "search the graph for `x`" and "restart the interpreter"? These can be on separate computers. I've heard of the SOA solution, but I'm not sure how to set that up or if the interpreter stays open after calls from Rails. Can someone point me to some guide, or give me advice?

Comment: You could run a microframework on another computer and expose a web API

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using Flask with localtunnel. It works.